# TCM_GETITEMRECT + TCM_ADJUSTRECT to get Tab client area

Tags: winapi, user32

I'm trying to get the client area of a tab control using `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` + `TCM_GETITEMRECT`, I call `TCM_GETITEMRECT` giving it the tab index then with that Rec filled in, call `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` passing either true or false but when ever I move the only tab child window with MoveWindow:

```
User32.MoveWindow(hdl,r.left,r.top,width,height,1)
```

it's either cropped at the top or cropped at the bottom depending on the boolean passed to `TCM_ADJUSTRECT`, I'm assuming its because the width and height values in `MoveWindow` are from the tab control itself and I need to work out the client height from the `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` but I'm not really sure how to get the width and height from the Rec structure:

```
typedef struct _RECT {
  LONG left;
  LONG top;
  LONG right;
  LONG bottom;
} RECT, *PRECT;
```

Comment: rect width: right - left, rect height: bottom - top

Comment: thanks user2120666, you knw now knowing how to work out the height has helped but the returned REC is still off a bit although its easy to correct by deducting 5 pixels from the right.